# Can't update a dbf from Java using dBase Driver

Tags: java, foxpro, dbf, dbase

Hello i have a dbf file that i want to update but everytime that i try to run the update statement the system says `that the Index is not found` that is using the `Microsoft dBase driver`.

This is the code:

```
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        String connString="jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft dBASE Driver (*.dbf)};DefaultDir=Path";
        Connection connection=DriverManager.getConnection(connString);


        String sql;

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.getTime();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");


        String _time =sdf.format(cal.getTime());//Adding the Time of set the product.



        sql="UPDATE [MESAS] SET PER_MEZ="+args[2]+", HOR_MEZ='"+_time+"', MES_MEZ='"+args[2]+"' WHERE COD_MEZ='M01'";

    Statement query = connection.createStatement();
    query.execute(sql);
```

Comment: I assume Java is the same as C# and you should be protecting against SQL injection ...

Comment: You've added a foxpro tag. What type of table is this really? dBase or FoxPro?

Comment: The dBase driver opens the fox pro tables, the problem is when i try to read a character field that is with troubles.

Comment: Try the Visual FoxPro driver instead. There may be some incompatibility.

Comment: Where i can find that driver?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [executeUpdate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate%28java.lang.String%29) instead of [execute](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#execute%28java.lang.String%29). There are some strange problems with execute while doing the table UPDATE.

Comment: But when i do a Select comes the same mistake.